# For loop vs List Comprehension gives me None as answer

Tags: python, list, for-loop, list-comprehension

I want to append words to a list. If I conduct a for loop the answers returned are correct.

However, if I conduct a list comprehension method I get None for the answers. What am I doing wrong?

```
x=[]
for i in range(0,10):
    x.append('hi'+str(i))
print(x)
```

Answer : `['hi0', 'hi1', 'hi2', 'hi3', 'hi4', 'hi5', 'hi6', 'hi7', 'hi8', 'hi9']`

```
x= [x.append('hi'+str(i)) for i in range(0,10)]

print(x)
```

Answer : `[None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None]`

Comment: What you mean is `x= ['hi'+str(i) for i in range(0,10)]`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does "list comprehension" mean? How does it work and how can I use it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34835951/what-does-list-comprehension-mean-how-does-it-work-and-how-can-i-use-it)

Comment: Don't use `x.append` in the list comprehension, just use `"hi"+str(i)`. You just spell out what element makes up the list. The `append` returns nothing (i.e., `None`) and hence you end up with a list full of `None`s.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use `append` as you are inside the list and `append` does return None in all cases.

```
x= ['hi'+str(i) for i in range(0,10)]

print(x)
```

Comment: Ahh yes, because I am within the list already. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Your `x = [x.append('hi'+str(i)) for i in range(0,10)]`, build a list with the result of each `x.append` call, which is None, as it is done inplace, then you erase `x` with that new list

You want

```
x = [f"hi{i}" for i in range(10)]
```